# Aligning posts in a django project + mdl

Tags: python, css, django, grid, alignment

[image]I am making a blog with django but when I try to align them next to each other,
they appear under each other.
the posts appear under each other.
how can i make them horizontally aligned.
**here is my html:**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load blog_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout ">
{% for post in posts %}
<main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="mdl-grid ">
        <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <figure class="mdl-card__media">
                <img src="{{ post.photo }}" alt="" />
            </figure>
            <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h1 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{ post.title }}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                <p>{{ post.body|truncatewords:11 }}</p>
            </div>
                            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
<a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect kal" href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">Read More</a>
<div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
    <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored kal"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></button>
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored kal"><i class="material-icons">share</i></button>
  </div>
        </div>


{% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

css file:
I think the problem is with this css file but i had trouble finding it
css file:
I think the problem is with this css file but i had trouble finding itcss file:
I think the problem is with this css file but i had trouble finding itcss file:
I think the problem is with this css file but i had trouble finding itcss file:
I think the problem is with this css file but i had trouble finding itcss file:
I think the problem is with this css file but i had trouble finding it

```
body{
background: white;
}
.mdl-grid {
max-width: 600px;
}
.mdl-card__media {
margin: 0;
}
.mdl-card__media > img {
max-width: 100%;
}
.mdl-card__actions {
display: flex;
box-sizing:border-box;
align-items: center;
}
.mdl-card__actions > .mdl-button--icon {
margin-right: 3px;
margin-left: 3px;
}
.kal:hover{
text-decoration: none;
}



    .main{
        font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
      font-size: 600%;
      color: white;
      border: None;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 9%;
        left: 6%;

    }
    .skills{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 5%;
        left: 6%;
        color: white;
    }
    .iff{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 9%;
        right: 9%;
    }
    .ten{
      color: black;
      background: white;
      font-size: 300%;
      border-radius: 300px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 30px;

    }
    .navbar{
      border-radius: 0px !important;
      background:  transparent;
      width: 100% !important;
      border: None !important;
      font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
      position: fixed !important;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1 !important;
    }
    .nad{
        font-size: 120% !important;
    }
    li:hover{
      font-weight: bold;
      background: white;

    }
    .navbar-brand{
      font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size-adjust: auto;
      font-size: 200% !important;
      color: black !important;
    }
    header{
        background: url("https://wp-themes.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/images/header.jpg");
      background-attachment: fixed;
        height: 100vh;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;

    }
    .tn{
      background: white;
      border-radius: 250px;
      color: black;
    }
    .main1{
      font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave Display', cursive;
    }
    .tab{
      font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    }
    .tab12{
      font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    }
```

Comment: Please include a summary of what you have tried and the ***relevant code*** in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this is how it looks like, look at the question

Comment: Please include *all of your relevant code* in the question. For example you know that this relates to CSS as you have tagged it, but you haven't included your CSS... which is actually what is responsible for aligning elements. Please *re-read the link in my previous comment and update your question with information that will actually help us to understand the problem*.

Comment: I added the css file above

Comment: @FluffyKitten I added the css file above